# Question about getting Review services

Tags: nt.number-theory

Hello.

I am currently doing some mathematics as an amateur, and recently I got to
publish an article at the Journal of Mathematics Research (JMR). The doi
for the article is 10.5539/jmr.v4n6p12 . And now, I have been trying to
get readers.

My real question, nevertheless, is whether it would be possible that my paper be reviewed by Mathematical Reviews, or Zentralblatt Math? I am asking this question because according to some sites on the Internet, journals which publish papers with payment have an accordingly poor peer-reviewing process, and I tend to think that my article may not be reviewed because of that.

If the answer is no, then I might want to hear whether my result is new.

If the answer is yes, then I might leave the task of final validation of my work for the reviewer of either one of those organizations, and will be quiet.

With regards,

Comment: For those readers who have not bothered to look at the article being linked to, it is 10 pages long and claims to prove the Lindelof hypothesis.

Comment: Hisanobu Shinya, since you presumably claim your result is correct, why didn't you choose any of the leading journals? 

Comment: It seems that your paper *will* be indexed in Zentralblatt MATH, see http://www.ccsenet.org/journal/index.php/jmr/about/editorialPolicies#custom-0

Comment: Anyway, it seems that the discussion has been closed.

I have been extremely thankful for the Journal of Mathematics Research, and as an action to show my respect to them in my own way, I have chosen not to put my latest version on arxiv; that's why the published version does not (and will never) appear on arxiv.

Thanks guys for advices.


Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many if not most reputable journals state up front whether their production is reviewed by Mathematical Reviews and/or Zentralblatt Math. This can work as a heuristic when deciding where to submit a paper you write, to ascertain that it gets the treatment you would expect for it.

MR and ZBM are not venues for peer-review; they are abstraction services to help mathematicians keep up to speed with already published, peer-reviewed mathematics.

Answer (score 8):

Journals which publish papers for money should not be considered serious journals, and if your purpose
of publishing a paper is that it is read by mathematicians, you should not send it in such journals.

If you really wish your paper to be read by mathematicians, publish it on the arxiv.

If your goal is something different, this is a wrong web site to ask.

Comment: See http://arxiv.org/abs/0706.0357